# Setting swagger config parameters in SpringDoc

Tags: swagger, springdoc

I am trying to override Swagger configuration in SpringDoc as described in:

https://springdoc.org/#swagger-ui-properties

I am setting these in the code in (kotlin class) init block

```
init {
    System.setProperty("springdoc.swagger-ui.path", "/services/$serviceName")
    System.setProperty("springdoc.swagger-ui.url", "/services/$serviceName/v3/api-docs")
    System.setProperty("springdoc.swagger-ui.configUrl", "/services/$serviceName/v3/api-docs/swagger-config")
    // Controls the display of extensions (pattern, maxLength, minLength, maximum, minimum) fields and values for Parameters.
    System.setProperty("springdoc.swagger-ui.showCommonExtensions", "true")
}
```

However it seems to be completely ignored and none of the fields are taken into account. What is the place these should be set correctly?

Note that I need to set the config properties according to the `SERVICE_NAME` env var, so I cannot use the static properties file.

Full config here: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/852f67f1688ea6e808b8eb89068e90d1

Comment: These properties go in your properties file. For a Spring app, the default properties file is  `application.properties` or `application.yml` under `src/main/resources`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by the SpringDoc author in https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1485, this can be done as follows:

```kotlin
    @Bean
    open fun swaggerUiConfig(config: SwaggerUiConfigProperties): SwaggerUiConfigProperties {
        // For details, see https://springdoc.org/#swagger-ui-properties
        // Controls the display of extensions (pattern, maxLength, minLength, maximum, minimum) fields and values for Parameters.
        config.showCommonExtensions = true
        // Allows to configure source for the documentation via query params (?url=/v3/api-docs).
        config.queryConfigEnabled = true
        return config
    }
```